# How to add data in list below previous one?

Tags: android

I want to add data in list. When I click the button, it takes data from different classes and adds it as a row in the list and comes back.

And again, when I insert data in form and press the button, it adds it below the previous one on another row. So an array is created of rows, and now when I click on any position of list item row, I get its content. So how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is whenever you add new data in the list you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. For getting its content you need to write `onItemClickListener()` and in listener you can get the content through its position id.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But from what I understand, you what to use a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).
In either case, you will need an adapter which manages the data displayed in the list. I would suggest that your "different class" which provides the data should subclass [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

You can then bind the class providing the data to the view using [`setAdapter(ListAdapter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

When your data changes, all you need to do is call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your data class which provides the data and the view will be updated.

To get the clicked item, you will need to create and set an `OnItemClickListener` on your ListView
See [this list activity example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

deep copy the generated list and append it to the previous array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you express this solution as code so that it's easier to use it?

Comment: vowels = []
xx='a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
vowels.append(xx)      or import copy
vowels = [['a','b']]
xx='a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
newdata=copy.deepcopy(xx)
vowels.append(newdata)